# user. File looking for user name in files

Tags: database, waze

I extracted the "user." file from the waze app for iPhone 6. In that file they have "Realtime.Name:" is that the same as the username. I also see "Realtime.FirstName" and "Realtime.LastName:" I am pretty sure those are the "Full name" fields. I am looking for the username.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow whenever ask a Question Please! describe what the problem are you facing.

Comment: I don't see the difficulty in verifying this yourself? If your own username is located there, it stands to reason that this will be the case for all other Waze users as well (except for perhaps older versions of the app).